# radius of convergence of $1/(1+z^2)$ about $z=2$ using geometric series approach

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, convergence-divergence, taylor-expansion

I would like to calculate the radius of convergence of $f(z)= 1/(1+z^2)$ about $z=2$ using the geometric series approach.

Let me first state that according to a theorem, the radius of convergence about a point $z_o$ is the smallest distance from $z_o$ to a singularity.

Using this method, the distances from $z=2$ to the singularities $z=i$ and $z=-i$ are $\sqrt{5}$ which is the radius of convergence. However, I get a different answer using the geometric series approach.

I can re-write f(z) as $(1/5)/(1+(4/5)(z-2)+(1/5)(z-2)^2)$. Comparing this to the expression $1/(1+z)$, we want $|(4/5)(z-2)+(1/5)(z-2)^2|<1$ for convergence.
This results in $|z|<3$ implying the radius of convergence is $3-2=1$.

Why is the answer here different?

thanks

Comment: How did you get $|z|<3$?

Comment: $|(4/5)(z−2)+(1/5)(z−2)^2 |<1$ implies $|4(z−2)+(z−2)^2 |<5$ which implies $|z^2 - 4| < 5$ which implies $z^2<9$

Comment: I have question: how can you rewrite f(z) as $(1/5)/(1+(4/5)(z-2)+(1/5)(z-2)^2)$. The talyor expansion of f(z) should be $(1/5)(1-4/5(z-2)+(11/25)(z-2)^2+O(z-2)^3)$

Comment: I simply re-wrote $1+z^2$ as $5+4(z−2)+(z−2)^ 2 $

Comment: I just use one counterexample to countermand your statement of |z|<3, when z = 4, f(z)= 1/17, But $4/5(z-2)+(z-2)^2/5 = 2.4$ So what's wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The geometric series approach does not work naively here to find the radius of convergence.  You are correct that the radius of convergence of the series $$\frac{1}{5}\sum_{n=0}^\infty \left(-\frac{4}{5}(z-2)-\frac{1}{5}(z-2)^2\right)^n$$ around $z=2$ is $1$ (here by "radius of convergence" I mean the radius of the largest disk around $2$ on which it converges--but this disk is actually not the entire set on which the series converges).  However, the partial sums of this series are *not* the same as the partial sums of the Taylor series for $f(z)$ around $z=2$.  Indeed, notice that each term of the geometric series, when expanded, contributes to several different terms of the Taylor series, since it will involve several different powers of $z-2$.  Each term of the Taylor series is actually a combination of pieces from several different terms of the geometric series.  So if you cut off the geometric series at a certain point, you have all of the contributions to some of the terms of the Taylor series, but also some partial contributions to later terms of the Taylor series.

So since the two series do not have the same partial sums, there is no obvious reason they should converge for the same values of $z$.  And in this case, they indeed do not.  It turns out that when you group together the terms from the geometric series according to the power of $z-2$ they contain, some magic cancellation happens which makes the radius of convergence increase from $1$ to $\sqrt{5}$.

In fact, the set on which the geometric series converges is not even a disk centered at $2$ at all--it is the funny-shaped region $|z^2-4|<5$.  You can compare the regions of convergence of the Taylor series and the geometric series at http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=implicit+plot+(x%5E2-y%5E2-4)%5E2%2B(2xy)%5E2%3D25+and++(x-2)%5E2%2By%5E2%3D5.  The nice circle is the region where the Taylor series converges, and the weird lumpy thing is the region where the geometric series converges.

Comment: Interesting answer, thanks. Dr. Lubin above also provided a strategy to find the correct radius of convergence. My issue was that I failed to realized that radius of convergence referred to a power series, and as you stated, the partial sums of my geometric series was not a proper power series.

Comment: Yeah, I said the geometric series approach does not work "naively" because I figured there might be some more clever way to use geometric series to find the correct radius of convergence.  As Lubin's answer shows, this more clever way is to use partial fractions to get a sum of geometric series where the ratios will be monomials in $z-2$.

Comment: This has been great discussion. Thanks to all who chimed in.

Answer (score 4):

Your strategy looks exactly right to me, but somewhere you went off the rails. Let me make typing and notation easier by setting $z-2=t$, $z=t+2$. Then the mathematics becomes much clearer. You have
$$
\frac1{1+z^2}=\frac1{1+(t+2)^2}=\frac15\biggl[\frac1{1+\frac45t+\frac15t^2}\biggr]\,,
$$
and I agree totally. But then, using Quadratic Formula, you should factor the denominator of the fraction in brackets, $1+\frac45t+\frac15t^2=(1-\alpha t)(1-\bar\alpha t)$, with $\alpha=\frac{-2+i}5$, a complex quantity of absolute value $1\big/\sqrt5$. Without bothering to do the actual computation, you know that
$$
\frac1{(1-\alpha t)(1-\bar\alpha t)}=\frac A{1-\alpha t}+\frac B{1-\bar\alpha t}\,.
$$
This says that the radii of convergence of the two series are both $|1/\alpha|=|1/\bar\alpha|=\sqrt5$, and I think this is the way that it was hoped that you would get the answer.

Notice that we don’t care what $A$ and $B$ are, but if I’ve not gone astray, $A=\bar B=(3-4i)/5$. This is enough for you to see that when you add the two complex series together term by term, you get a real series, as of course you must.

Comment: Dr. Lubin, thanks. I failed to realize that radius of convergence referred to the Taylor series (at least in the case), and the partial sums of the geometric series does not follow the partial sums of the taylor series- i.e the series are different. Your method allows one to express f(z) as a sum of two taylor series, which happens to also be a geometric series, hence this case the geometric series and taylor series agree.